# Executing SSIS package programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I writing to execute SSIS package using the application. I have written following code but it gives an error. the error is listed below the code.

```
        public void RunPackage()
    {
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;

        pkgLocation = @"C:\Users\EMISDb\Desktop\NEOC\EOC data need\NEOC_ETL\NEOC_ETL\obj\Development\99_Dash_WHO.dtsx";
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

    }
```

error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4F0FC44B-C99C-4 
>   41D-B86A-D60D7E22143D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
>   registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
>   about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving 
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4F0FC44B-C99C-441D-B86A-
>   D60D7E22143D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
>   registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

The error at the following line.

```
Line 27:             app = new Application();
```

Comment: Try compiling for x86.

Comment: have you tried registering the class?, the message suggests that the dts runtime wrapper is not registered.

Comment: Which versions of SQL Server and SSDT you are using ?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2014 but SSDT is 2017

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this error and installing [SQL Server 2017 x64 Express with Advanced Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994) resolved the issue.

It installed `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTS.dll` and registered the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91` in
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{4F0FC44B-C99C-441D-B86A-D60D7E22143D}`.