# Error in executing SSIS package using mvc C#

Tags: ssis

I am working to run/execute SSIS package from my application developed in MVC 5. 
The package is developed using Visual studio 2017 data tools. 
I have written the following code to run the package

```
            try

        {

            Application app = new Application();

            Package package = null;

            package = app.LoadPackage(@"‪C:\Users\EMISDb\Desktop\NEOC\EOC data need\NEOC_ETL\NEOC_ETL\99_Dash_WHO.dtsx", null);
            //Excute Package 

            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();

            if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)

            {
                foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Package Execution results: {0}", local_DtsError.Description.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine();

                }

            }

        }

        catch (DtsException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

but when i run, it gives the following error message. I tried to find 64 bit but could not find to install. Any help please.

```
**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4F0FC44B-C99C-441D-B86A-D60D7E22143D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**
```

and

```
**An Integration Services class cannot be found. Make sure that Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is running the application. Also, make sure that the 64-bit version of Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64-bit application.**        '
```

Comment: Do you have SSIS installed on the computer that is running your MVC application?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: ... and started?

Comment: yes it is started

Comment: Do you have a program called `DTEXEC.EXE` on your computer? What happens when you run `DTEXEC /H`

Comment: when i run DTEXEC /H a the command prompt just prompts and disappear

Comment: You need to open a command prompt by typing `CMD`. Then in there, type `DTEXEC /H`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing SSIS package programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985032/executing-ssis-package-programmatically-using-c-sharp)